# Python.exe has stopped working error while running jupyter

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am currently writing a script that extracts 10000 URLs from a website and then accesses each URL link to extract information like dates, country codes, etc. The program works fine when I use a lesser number of URLs, but when I repeat it for all 10000 URLs, I get an error "python.exe has stopped working". Is there any way to stop this from happening? P. S. I am using bs4 package for this program.

Comment: Does it happen while running, or at the start of the script? Maybe a memory error/overload?

Comment: i actually had the same issue last week. It has to do with the memory. If you go through the error message, you will notice it has 'memory error' as part of the output. Paste the full error message for us to have a look at.

Comment: @NielsHenkens This tends to happen while running the script, midway...

Comment: Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: What if you write your data to a file after each x URL's and continue with a new/empty list/dataframe/.. ?

Comment: Still having the same issues..